# react-native info not detecting Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

On my mac, to be able to develop react-native apps, I installed react-native-cli and create-react-native-app using npm.

When I run:

```
react-native info
```

I see the following output:

```
Environment:
  OS:  macOS Sierra 10.12.6
  Node:  6.11.4
  Yarn:  Not Found
  npm:  3.10.10
  Watchman:  4.9.0
  Xcode:  Not Found
  Android Studio:  Not Found

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.0.0-alpha.12 => 16.0.0-alpha.12
  react-native: ^0.48.4 => 0.48.4
```

As you can see, Xcode is shown as "Not Found". I am running Xcode 9 on my system.

What should I be checking for / installing on my OS for react-native to work with Xcode 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed Expo XDE and tried to create and run a project from there. I saw this error in the XDE. Helped me solve the problem.

> Simulator not installed. Please visit 
>   https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/ to download Xcode and 
>   the iOS simulator. If you already have the latest version of Xcode
>   installed, you may have to run the command 
>   `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thanks for reminding. I had struggled with this for 8 hours before I posted it. I just happened to hit an alternate workflow after I posted. There are no posts that come up in Search with these keywords.